# How to inject Global constant to a vue component <style>?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vue-component, bulma

I'm searching how to inject a global (`THEME_NAME` in my example) to all the vue components:

```
<template>..</template>
<style lang="scss">
    @import "bulmaswatch/<%=THEME_NAME=>/bulmaswatch.scss";

    .foo {
      color: $primary;
    }
</style>
```

Context:

I'm using the [`darkly` theme](https://jenil.github.io/bulmaswatch/) of [bulma css](https://bulma.io/) in my vue application (vue Cli 3)

```
<template>..</template>
<style lang="scss">
    @import "bulmaswatch/darkly/bulmaswatch.scss";
    .foo {
        color: $primary;
    }
</style>
```

In order to switch to the `cyborg` theme, I will have to replace `darkly` with `cyborg` everywhere...

Is there a better way? Something like

```
<template>..</template>
<style lang="scss">
    @import "bulmaswatch/<%=THEME_NAME=>/bulmaswatch.scss";

    .foo {
      color: $primary;
    }
</style>
```

then somewhere in `Webpack` or `vue.config.js`, we can decide what is the theme

```
configureWebpack: () => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                THEME_NAME: "cyborg"
            }),
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe DefinePlugin only works for JavaScript, you'll have to use something like [string-replace-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jamesandersen/string-replace-webpack-plugin) instead. It's too bad SASS doesn't support dynamic `@import` statements like LESS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to switch to the cyborg theme, I will have to replace darkly with cyborg everywhere...

Not if you use the **re-export** pattern.
There's no need for any external libraries and codegen magics with webpack.

Basically, you create a file where you import your theme.
Let's call it `_my-bulma-theme.scss` and let's import `darkly` for now.

```
// _my-bulma-theme.scss
@import "bulmaswatch/darkly/bulmaswatch.scss";
```

In your code, you import this file instead of importing from Bulma directly:

```
// some-component.vue
<style>
  @import "../../my-bulma-theme";
</style>

// some-other-component.vue
<style>
  @import "../../my-bulma-theme";
</style>
```

Now, when you want to change the theme, you just need to change it in one place: the `_my-bulma-theme.scss` file.

```
// _my-bulma-theme.scss
@import "bulmaswatch/cyborg/bulmaswatch.scss";
```